# How to fix up the error in matrix dimensions in MATLAB R2016b

Tags: matlab

I am working on a MATLAB code that involves deep learning using neural networks.
The image or the data is being fed in the form of matrices.
But I am getting an error "Matrix dimensions must agree".
Can Someone please help me with this problem?

I tried to solve this problem by using `.*` in stead of matrix multiplication `*` but the method didn't work.

Function `Deeplearningoriginal`:

```
function [w1,w2,w3,w4] = Deeplearningoriginal(w1,w2,w3,w4,input_Image,correct_output)
alpha=0.01;
N=5;
for k = 1:N
input_Image = reshape( input_Image( :, :,k ),25 ,1);

input_of_hidden_layer1 = w1* input_Image;
output_of_hidden_layer1 = ReLU(input_of_hidden_layer1);

input_of_hidden_layer2 = w2* output_of_hidden_layer1;
output_of_hidden_layer2 = ReLU( input_of_hidden_layer2);


input_of_hidden_layer3 = w3* output_of_hidden_layer2;
output_of_hidden_layer3 = ReLU(input_of_hidden_layer3);

input_of_output_node = w4* output_of_hidden_layer3;
final_output = Softmax(input_of_output_node);

correct_output_transpose = correct_output(k,:);
error = correct_output_transpose - final_output;

delta4 = error;

error_of_hidden_layer3 = w4'* delta4;
delta3 = (input_of_hidden_layer3>0).*error_of_hidden_layer3;

error_of_hidden_layer2 = w3'* delta3;
delta2 = (input_of_hidden_layer2>0).* error_of_hidden_layer2;

error_of_hidden_layer1 = w2'*delta2;
delta1 = (input_of_hidden_layer1>0).* error_of_hidden_layer1;

adjustment_of_w4 = alpha*delta4*output_of_hidden_layer3';
adjustment_of_w3 = alpha*delta3*output_of_hidden_layer2';
adjustment_of_w2 = alpha*delta2*output_of_hidden_layer1';
adjustment_of_w1 = alpha*delta1*reshaped_input_image';

w1 = w1 + adjustment_of_w1;
  w2 = w2 + adjustment_of_w2;
    w3 = w3 + adjustment_of_w3;
      w4 = w4 + adjustment_of_w4;
end
end
```

Training network:

```
input_Image = zeros (5,5,5);

input_Image(:,:,1) = [ 1 0 0 1 1;
                   1 1 0 1 1;
                   1 1 0 1 1;
                   1 1 0 1 1;
                   1 0 0 0 1;
                   ];
input_Image(:,:,2) = [ 0 0 0 0 1;
                   1 1 1 1 0;
                   1 0 0 0 1;
                   0 1 1 1 1;
                   0 0 0 0 0;
                   ];
input_Image(:,:,3) = [ 0 0 0 0 1;
                   1 1 0 0 1;
                   1 0 1 0 1;
                   0 0 0 0 0;
                   1 1 1 0 1;
                   ];
input_Image(:,:,4) = [ 1 1 1 0 1;
                   1 1 0 0 1;
                   1 0 1 0 1;
                   0 0 0 0 0;
                   1 1 1 0 1;
                   ];
input_Image(:,:,5) = [ 0 0 0 0 0;
                   0 1 1 1 1;
                   0 0 0 0 1;
                   1 1 1 1 0;
                   0 0 0 0 1;
                   ];
correct_output    =  [ 1 0 0 0 0;
                   0 1 0 0 0;
                   0 0 1 0 0;
                   0 0 0 1 0;
                   0 0 0 0 1;
                  ];
w1 = 2* rand(20,25) -1;
w2 = 2* rand(20,20) -1;
w3 = 2* rand(20,20) -1;
w4 = 2* rand(5,20) -1;

for epoch = 1:100
  [w1,w2,w3,w4] = Deeplearningoriginal(w1,w2,w3,w4,input_Image,correct_output);
end
```

I expected this code to run but because of the error I am not able to proceed.

Comment: Thank you ,please correct the errors in the above code,i tried to rectify ,but i'm not getting the correct output..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `reshape` (actually, two problems). After the

```
input_image = reshape(input_image(:,:,k), 25,1);
```

`input_image` is an array with 25 rows and 1 column, whereas `w2`, `w3`, and `w4` have only 20 columns. To do the matrix multiplication `A*B`, `A` must have as many columns as `B` has rows.

The other problem with the `reshape` as written is that after the first pass through the loop, `input_image` is no longer a `5x5x5` array, it is a `25x1` array that contains only the elements of `input_image(:,:,1)`. It is necessary to use a different name on the left-hand-side of the assignment (and throughout the rest of the loop) to avoid loosing the content of `input_image`.

Hope this helps,

JAC

Comment: Thank you JAC, JAC I tried to sort out that matrix dimensions error,but again i'm not getting the correct output,please edit my code to resolve that problem.

Comment: @ARJUN N. It's not much help my editing your code, mainly because I don't know what you are trying to do. Neural networks is not my field. You may try first checking your data. For example what are `w1` to `w4`? Why are they different sizes? As long as they don't have 25 columns each, there is a dimension mismatch with the reshaped `input_image` which will keep triggering the "Matrix dimensions must agree" error message. Try solving this part of the problem first.

Comment: I'm actually trying to get these [ 1 0 0 0 0;
                   0 1 0 0 0;
                   0 0 1 0 0;
                   0 0 0 1 0;
                   0 0 0 0 1;
                  ]; As the desired output ,when I give the  ,input image as input , okay I'll try to fix with that.Thank you again.